# Inverse quaternion

Tags: c, quaternions

Can anyone tell me how to get the inverse of quaternion.

```
q-1=q'/(q*q')
```

q' = Quaternion conjugate

(q*q') = norm of a quaternion * norm of a quaternion

I have my quaternion: (C language)

```
quat.x = 0.0;
quat.y = 1.0;
quat.z = 0.0;
quat.w = 45.0;
```

First conjugate:

```
quat.conjx =  0.0;
quat.conjy = -1.0;
quat.conjz =  0.0;
quat.conjw = 45.0;
```

Next: Norm

```
quat.norm = sqrt(quat.x*quat.x + quat.y*quat.y + quat.z*quat.z + quat.w*quat.w);
```

Ok but... How do I calculate the inverse using C syntax? This is right?:

```
quat.invx = quat.conjx / (quat.norm*quat.norm);
quat.invy = quat.conjy / (quat.norm*quat.norm);
quat.invz = quat.conjz / (quat.norm*quat.norm);
quat.invw = quat.conjw / (quat.norm*quat.norm);
```

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: In this post using C syntax?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The other question answered in Haskell.

Comment: The formula for the inverse is as follows:  `inverse = conjugate(q) / norm(q)`

[I wrote a C-library that does this.](https://github.com/dagostinelli/hypatia/blob/master/src/quaternion.c)  

I would create a new answer, but this is a closed question.

Answer (score 3):

The conjugate of a quaternion *x* + i *y* + j *z* + k *w* is defined as *x* - i *y* - j *z* - k *w*.  There aren't three separate conjugates. Also, don't try putting `norm`, `invx`, `invy`, `invz`, `conjx`, etc. into your quaternion structure. Just write:

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
    double w;
} quaternion;
```

and then write functions that take quaternions as arguments and return them. For example, write:

```
// Construct and return the conjugate of q.
quaternion q_conjugate(const quaternion q) { ...}
// Divide quaternion q by scalar d
quaternion q_divide(const quaternion q, const double divisor) {...}
// Compute the squared norm of q
double q_squared_norm(const quaternion q) {...}
// Compute the inverse of q
quaternion q_inverse(const quaternion q);
```

Comment: Ah then the conjugate of my quaternion is 0-1-0-45 = -46.0 ?

Comment: No, it's 0.0 - 1.0 i - 0.0 j - 45.0 k.  Just as a complex number *x* + i *y* can be thought of as a vector in the plane, a quaternion can be thought of as a vector in R^4. Its conjugate is another vector in R^4. Adding the components is meaningless.

Comment: All right but, can you tell me how to do calculate q_inverse using C syntax. Thank you